# Using TikZ coordinates in expressions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I would like to be able to calculate two new `\coordinate`s by starting from two existing coordinates. I have defined two coordinates `c1` and `c2`. A minimal example would be

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(.05\textwidth,0)},y={(0,.05\textwidth)}]
    \def\arrowlength{0.5}
    \coordinate (c1) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (c2) at (4,1);

    \draw (c1) -- (c2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Continuing from here, I would like to calculate a third coordinate, `c3`, that lies in the middle of `c1` and `c2`. I have tried

```
\coordinate (c3) at (0.5*c1+0.5*c2);
```

but that gives me the error

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named 0 is known
```

Second, I would like to draw an arrow from `c3`, orthogonal to the line between `c1` and `c2`. So I would like to take the difference `c2-c1`, rotate that vector by `90` degrees, normalize it, multiply it with the length the arrow is supposed to have, then add it to `c3` and store it as a new coordinate called `c4`. Is this possible? (I want to avoid calculating the coordinates manually since I have to do this a lot of times and I want to be able to make changes to it easily)

**Edit 1:** Thanks to Jake and percusse, I reallized that I have to enclose the expression in $-signs and enclose the coordinates in parentheses. I have now updated the minimal example to

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(.05\textwidth,0)},y={(0,.05\textwidth)}]
    \def\arrowlength{0.5}
    \coordinate (c1) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (c2) at (4,1);
    \coordinate (c3) at (5,0);

    \coordinate (c4) at ($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$);
    \coordinate (c5) at ($(c4)!\arrowlength!90:(c2)$);

    \coordinate (c6) at ($(c2)!0.5!(c3)$);
    \coordinate (c7) at ($(c6)!\arrowlength!90:(c3)$);

    \draw (c1) -- (c2) -- (c3);
    \draw[->] (c4) -- (c5);
    \draw[->] (c6) -- (c7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the image

[image: Arrows are not equally long]

As can be seen, the arrows are not equally long, so replacing `2cm` (which Jake used) with `0.5` (which I assumed would automatically, like all other coordinates specified without a unit, use the `x` and `y` vectors) did apparently not work. Any ideas for how to specify the length of the arrow in terms of "unit lengths"? (The coordinate `(4,1)` for example is 4 unit lengths in the `x`-direction and 1 unit length in the `y`-direction)

**Edit 2:**

I updated my example according to Jakes suggestion to

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \def\unitlength{0.05\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(\unitlength,0)},y={(0,\unitlength)}]
    \def\arrowlength{0.5*\unitlength}
    \coordinate (c1) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (c2) at (4,1);
    \coordinate (c3) at (5,0);

    \coordinate (c4) at ($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$);
    \coordinate (c5) at ($(c4)!\arrowlength!90:(c2)$);

    \coordinate (c6) at ($(c2)!0.5!(c3)$);
    \coordinate (c7) at ($(c6)!\arrowlength!90:(c3)$);

    \draw (c1) -- (c2) -- (c3);
    \draw[->] (c4) -- (c5);
    \draw[->] (c6) -- (c7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and now the arrows are equally long.

Comment: For questions like this, you should always post a minimal example document.

Comment: @Jake: Got it – I will try to remember that in the future.

Comment: Under your nickname, it shows what percent of the questions you have asked has an *accepted* solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library for this. See section 13.5 Coordinate Calculations of the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf).

To get the halfway point between two coordinates, you can use the syntax `($(A)!0.5!(B)$)` or `($0.5*(A)+0.5*(B)$)`. For the rotated vector, you can use `($(A)!<length>!<angle>:(B)$)`.

The midpoint between two coordinates can also be found using a `\path` command, as Altermundus points out in a comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (C1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C2) at (3,2);

%% Use one of the next two lines for calculating the midpoint between two coordinates using the calc library...
\coordinate (C3) at ($(C1)!0.5!(C2)$);
%\coordinate (C3) at ($0.5*(C1)+0.5*(C2)$);

%% Or create coordinates C1, C2 and C3 in one go using a path command (thanks, Altermundus!)
%\path (0,0) coordinate (C1) -- coordinate (C3) (3,2) coordinate (C2);

\coordinate (C4) at ($(C3)!2cm!90:(C2)$);

\draw (C3) -- (C2);
\draw [red] (C3) -- (C4);

\node at (C1) {C1};
\node at (C2) {C2};
\node at (C3) {C3};
\node at (C4) {C4};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! But I'm running into problems when I'm trying to replace the `2cm` with a dimensionless quantity. I've updated my question to include that.

Comment: I can't think of a simple way to do this, since you can specify different lengths for `x` and `y`. What (physical) length would you expect the dimensionless length `1` to have? I would recommend defining a macro `\def\unitlength{0.05\textwidth}` before your `tikzpicture`, and using that macro both in the definition of `x` and `y` and in the coordinate calculations. In your example, you could use `\def\unitlength{0.05\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\unitlength,y=\unitlength]
    \def\arrowlength{0.5*\unitlength}`

Comment: That would definitely be a solution. I recal I have even used a similar method for another problem I ran in to.

Comment: Regarding what length I would expect `1` to have; if it is in the `x`-direction it would have the same length (and direction) as the `x`-vector, and corresponding for the case if it is in the `y`-direction. If the angle is not a multiple of `90` degrees, I guess you would first use trigonometry to calculate the unitless coordinate vector and then take the scalar product of that vector and the vector `(x,y)`.

Comment: Possible to get C3 : `\path (0,0) coordinate (C1) 
         -- coordinate (C3) 
      (3,2) coordinate (C2);`

Comment: @Altermundus: Good point! I've incorporated that approach in my answer.

Comment: Assuming the coordinate system is not skewed, the macro `\pgf@xx` holds the unit x vector. So `{\arrowlength*\pgf@xx}` would give 0.5 times the unit x vector. But requires `\makeatletter` somewhere before that

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Jake's answer, when one wants to do a little more complicated point weighting etc. the local `shift` and `scale` options are useful (both with `x` and `y` counterparts). They map to lower level PGF commands `\pgfpointadd` and `\pgfpointscale` commands.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (-1,-1) grid[step=1] (1,1);
\node (c1) at (1,1) {c1};
\node (c2) at (-1,-1) {c2};
\node (c3) at (-1,1) {c3};
\coordinate (c4) at ($([shift={(-1,-1)}]c1)+(c2)+([xscale=-1]c3)$);
\draw[-latex] (c4) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Although for `([shift={(-1,-1)}]c1)`, I'd prefer the equivalent expression `(c1)+(-1,-1)`, just because it uses less brackets.

Comment: @Jake Sure. But if you want to add and scale at the same time, it would cause some trouble. The order of the keys still matter.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that you could scale and shift coordinates that easily. I guess these are also options that you can give to `\draw`?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Yes, this also works : `\draw[shift={(2,2)},scale=2,rotate=90] (0,0) -- (1,1);`

Comment: How about 3D? and dot product? for example $(a_1,b_1,c_1).(a_2,b_2,c_2)=a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 c_3$ ?