# Middle of two coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

In `TikZ`, I have defined two coordinates by

```
\coordinate (A) (1, 2);
\coordinate (B) (5, 3);
```

Is there a simple way to define the middle of A and B? I'm looking for a command such as

```
\coordinate (M) (A)!0.5!(B);
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably `\coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);` with the `calc` library loaded

Comment: Or `\path (1,2) coordinate (A) -- coordinate (M) (5,3) coordinate (B);`. BTW, your syntax  `\coordinate (A) (1, 2);` is wrong, it should be `\coordinate (A) at (1, 2);` or `\path (1,2) coordinate (A);`.

Comment: As mentioned above, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66914/using-tikz-coordinates-in-expressions https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71478/how-to-center-one-node-exactly-between-two-others-with-tikz

Comment: @BambOo Can you write an answer? Thanks

Comment: As Torbjorn T. said, this is already answered in order posts.

Comment: Yes it's true, but I would say that adding the answer here can be positive for the TeX community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this answer is mostly a reminder of [Claudio Fiandrino's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71479/141947) or [Jake's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66915/141947) answers.

To compute coordinates based on two other coordinates, Ti*k*Z proposes the `calc` library depicted in details in section §13.5 of the `pgfmanual` (accessible on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or with `texdoc pgfmanual.pdf` if installed).

More specifically, the syntax required by the calc library to compute coordinates from others takes the form `($<coordinate 1>!<factor / dimension / coordinate>!<angle>:<coordinate 2>$)` and fall under the scope of so-called *Partway / Distance / Projection Modifiers*.

**Note the `($...$)` enclosing which is required !**

In your case, you are interested in the partway modification, because you try to compute the coordinates midway (hence at a 0.5-0.5 normalized distance) between two other ones.

In the end the syntax should therefore be `\coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);` where

- `<coordinate1> = (A)`
- `<factor> = 0.5` for the midway point
- `<angle> = {}` so assumed null
- `<coordinate2> = (B)`